# entry pattern "'./src/components/*.vue'" did not match any files / Building Web Components VUEJS

Tags: vue.js

```
    "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "wbuild": "vue-cli-service build --watch",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "build:target": "vue-cli-service build --target wc --name my-compo './src/components/*.vue'"
  },
```

I have two questions:
First: When I follow the documentation of "documents Build Target Vue.js" and I use `npm run build:target`, it does not work like mentioned in the documentation, but when I try to remove the single quotes `' '` then it does work, can someone explain this behaviour?

Second: Can I replace `--name my-compo` with `name` in the `.vue` file?
I want to have for example:
alert.vue -> my-compo.js -> alert.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it helps you to install https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env and prefix your script commands with `cross-env` like:

```
 "scripts": {
    "serve": "cross-env vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "cross-env vue-cli-service build",
    "wbuild": "cross-env vue-cli-service build --watch",
    "lint": "cross-env vue-cli-service lint",
    "build:target": "cross-env vue-cli-service build --target wc --name my-compo './src/components/*.vue'"
  },
```

The reason can be that your are also in windows, like me.